# Sublime Vintage Mode - adding lines

Tags: vim, sublimetext3

Im trying to add multiple lines in vim-emulation of sublime text 3 (vintage mode), but it doesn`t work.

To add 5 lines I`ve tried:

[command mode] - 5o
[command mode] - 5\o

Can Anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 :norm 5i ctrl-v ctrl-j enter
```

Where ctrl correspond to the proper key combination